# mysql find duplicates

Tags: mysql

```
id | apples  | oranges
1    111       p
2    112       p
3    113       p
4    113       f
5    113       -
6    114       p
7    114       f
8    115       -
9    115       -
10   116       f
```

Looking for a way to return only the rows where:

1. oranges contains value 'f' or no value (empty)
2. there are duplicate values in apples
3. at least one duplicate in applies contains value of 'p' in oranges.

The rows 4,5 & 7 in bold and italic are what I am after.

Comment: maybe it is just my eyes, but none of those things are in bold

Comment: @Woot4Moo It's your eyes, although the bold doesn't stand out that much to be honest. Look **really** closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a self-join. Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.apples = t2.apples
WHERE t1.oranges IN ('f', '-')
AND t2.oranges = 'p'
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97104/1)

Comment: SQL Fiddle is awesome! (didn't know it)

Comment: Why `AND t2.oranges = 'p'`? I think this isn't what the op wants

Comment: well the p part is for when dupes are found in apples

Comment: @MahmoudGamal From the question: "and at least one duplicate contains value of 'p' in oranges". So if we have one duplicate that satisfies this condition, we don't have to check for other duplicates and likewise if this condition is not satisfied, we do not care if there are 100 other duplicates. Therefore we can simplify the query to only this check.

Comment: I checked the SQL fiddle example and it works.  Thank you.  When trying this on a table with nearly a million records it takes way too long so I'll need to find a way to break this down.

Comment: @user1800522 Try putting an index on `apples` if there isn't one already

Answer (score 0):

Lets write these as three separate queries and then combine them.

> Looking for a way to return only the rows where oranges contains value
>   'f' or no value (empty)

```
select *   
from table  
where oranges = 'f'
or oranges is null;
```

> where there are duplicate values in apples and at least one duplicate
>   contains value of 'p' in oranges

```
select * 
( 
  select *
  from table    
  INNER JOIN (SELECT apples FROM inner_table
  GROUP BY apples HAVING count(id) > 1)
)
where oranges ='p'
```

And then you can combine them like so:

```
select *
(
    select *  
    from table  
    where (oranges ='f' or oranges is null)  
    INNER JOIN (SELECT apples FROM inner_table
  GROUP BY apples HAVING count(id) > 1)
)
where oranges ='p'
```

This is untested since I don't have a schema to work from.

Comment: I understood the question to mean `table` and `inner_table` are one in the same.

Comment: they are the same logical table, they are named to illustrate the variable that holds the temporary name.  A lot of my time is in Oracle lately so the syntax may look hokey.